# How many solutions of equation where the independent variables do not all have the same possible values?

Tags: combinatorics

Problem:
Let $x_1$, $x_2$, $x_3$ and $x_4$ be integers such that $x_1 > 0$, $x_2 > 0$,
$x_3 > 1$ and $x_4 > 1$. How many solutions does the following equation have:
$$ x_1 + x_2 + x_3 + x_4 = 40$$

Answer:

Let $c$ be the count we seek. First we consider the following question.
\newline
Let $x_1$, $x_2$, $x_3$ and $x_4$ be integers such that $x_1 > 0$, $x_2 > 0$,
$x_3 > 0$ and $x_4 0 1$. How many solutions does the following equation have:
$$ x_1 + x_2 + x_3 + x_4 = 40$$

This is the orginal problem modified to allow for the cases of $x_3 = 1$ and $x_4 = 1$. Let
$c_m$ be the solution to the modified problem. We can find $c_m$ using the stars and
bars method.
\newline
\begin{align*}
c_m &= { {40-1} \choose {4-1} } = { {39} \choose {3} } = \dfrac{ 39(38)(37) } {3(2)} \\
c_m &= \dfrac{ 39(19)(37)} {3} \\
c_m &= 9139
\end{align*}
However, $c_m$ includes solutions where $x_3 = 1$ and it includes solutions where
$x_4 = 1$. These solutions need to be subtracted out. Hence we now consider three
special cases. For the special case of $x_3 = 1$ we have:
$$ x_1 + x_2 + 1 + x_4 = 40$$
or
$$ x_1 + x_2 + x_4 = 39$$
Let $c_3$ be the number of solutions of the above equation.
\begin{align*}
c_3 &= { {39-1} \choose {3-1} } = { {38} \choose {2} } = \dfrac{ 38(37) } {2} \\
c_3 &= 703 \\
\end{align*}
Now we consider this equation:
$$ x_1 + x_2 + x_3 + 1 = 40$$
We claim that the number of solutions of this equation is $c_3$. Now consider the orginal equation with $x_3 = 1$ and $x_4 = 1$. This gives us:
$$ x_1 + x_2 + 1 + 1 = 40$$
or
$$ x_1 + x_2 = 38 $$
Call the number of solutions of this equation to be $c_{34}$. We have:
\begin{align*}
c &= c_m - 2*c_3 + c_{34} \\
c_{34} &= { {38-1} \choose {2-1} } = { {37} \choose {1} } \\
c_{34} &= 37 \\
c &= 9139 - 2(820) + 37 \\
c &= 7536
\end{align*}
I have reason to believe that the correct answer is: $7770$. Where did I go wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The way I would do it is to subtract $1$ from each of $x_3$ and $x_4$ and so $2$ from the total, making the question

> Let $x_1$, $x_2$, $y_3$ and $y_4$ be integers such that $x_1 > 0$, $x_2 > 0$,
> $y_3 > 0$ and $y_4 > 0$. How many solutions does the following equation have:
> $$ x_1 + x_2 + y_3 + y_4 = 38$$

to which there is a stars and bars solution of ${38-1 \choose 4-1} = 7770$.

As to your error, you changed $703$ to $820$ for no obvious reason. You started with ${40-1 \choose 4-1}$.  From this you would have to subtract the number with $x_3=1$ which is ${39-1 \choose 3-1}=703$, and the number with $x_4=1$ which is also ${39-1 \choose 3-1}$.  But this takes away the ${38-1 \choose 2-1}$ cases with both $x_3=1$ and $x_4=1$ twice instead of once, so you need to add it back as inclusion-exclusion.  You should then get $$9139-703-703+37 =7770$$

Comment: I originally computed $c_3$ as 820. Before posting, I fixed the error but I missed one spot.